# Extremely low token supply after token created on Tokenfactory via Metamask

Tags: tokens, erc-20

I used the parameters in the picture below to create a token for our organization, but instead of showing the desired token supply of 1000000000 & 18 decimals (similar to, say, the [MDT token](https://etherscan.io/token/0x814e0908b12a99fecf5bc101bb5d0b8b5cdf7d26) for instance), I'm seeing an extremely small supply - so small that it's showing as 0.000 tokens in many wallets, even for the person with 99.9990% of our supply: https://etherscan.io/token/0xfe385a02137339c1670845b353eea4753a05652a#balances

How can this issue be addressed? Is there a problem with Tokenfactory? Should I create a new token and just say 0 decimals instead, to avoid this issue? Can this apparent issue be fixed without creating a new token? Thank you!

[image: Tokenfactory token creation image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual totalSupply is supposed to be `tokens you want * 10^decimals`

Your current contract essentially says you want 0.000000001. What you want to say is "I want 1000000000 tokens, each with 18 decimals".

This makes your totalSupply `1000000000000000000000000000`.

Comment: In this case, what is the amount that should be entered in the first box on the tokenfactory site, if I wanted a similar supply as the MDT token? I think I'll create a new token, since it appears I cannot change the supply after it's created. Or is it possible to change the supply of this coin? Simple language appreciated, since this is the first time I've created a token ;)

Comment: I'm not certain if the token contract supports a supply change, most don't. As a general rule, decide on the number of tokens you want, and add 18 `0`s after it to get the total supply you should enter. So for `1000000000` tokens, you enter `1000000000000000000000000000` (and make sure your decimals are still 18)

Comment: Thanks Raghav! I think I've got the idea now, and will attempt creating a new token then.